# Successive differentiation of an implicit function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y^{1/m}+y^{-1/m}=2x$, prove that $$(x^2-1)y'''+3xy''+(1-m^2)y'=0$$

I used brute force(kept on applying Product and Quotient rule) and after almost 3 pages of nasty calculations was able to get to the result. I am looking for a faster and better approach. Thanks.

Comment: The form of the equation suggests substituting $y = u^m$, which transforms the equation to $u + \frac{1}{u} = 2 x$. Multiplying through by $u$ gives $$u^2 + 1 = 2 x u.$$ This is much cleaner to differentiate. There's still some ugly work rewriting $u^{(k)}$ in terms of $y^{(k)}, \ldots, y', y$, but it shouldn't be three pages of ugly work.

Comment: @Travis, using logarithmic derivatives seems to help, but I did not finish the computation.

Comment: As the first relationship can be written $\cosh(\dfrac{1}{m}ln(y))=x$ why not the change of variables $y=e^{m ArgCosh(x)}$ ?

Comment: I have some doubts (may be I am wrong) about your differential equation. Have you checked it ?

Comment: Yep, that is what is says in my source.

Comment: I had no notification of your answer : please think to indicate the targeted person.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$y^{\frac 1m}=e^u\Rightarrow u=\frac 1m \ln y\Rightarrow u'=\frac 1m\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)$$

Then we also have $$\cosh u =x\Rightarrow u = \operatorname{arcosh} x\Rightarrow u'=(x^2-1)^{-\frac 12}$$

We can rearrange this and square both sides so that $$(x^2-1)(u')^2=1\Rightarrow (x^2-1)\left(\frac 1m\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)\right)^2=1$$

Now rearrange this as $$(x^2-1)(y')^2=m^2y^2$$ and differentiate:
$$2x(y')^2+(x^2-1)2y'y''=2m^2yy'$$

Finally, cancel $2y'$ and differentiate again:
$$y'+xy''+2xy''+(x^2-1)y'''=m^2y'$$
And thus we are done.